# Installing hadoop on windows xp

Tags: hadoop

i am having problems while trying to install hadoop on windows32 bit 
i have followed the yahoo ttorial on installing hadoop
http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/
and have successfully downloaded the VMplayer and Hadoop virtual machine image,
but i am not able to configure the eclipse plug-in

using the jar i am able to write the basic map-reduce program in eclipse,Now after writing howw to execute them on hadoop as with hadoop vMimage i can not find the bin directory

Comment: can you please post the code .

Comment: It's not about the code is working or not
My basic Question is 
as i have downloaded the VirtualImage of hadoop then where to put the java or say.class file
to run it us

Answer (score 0):

Hortonworks has released windows version of hadoop by modifying shell scripts wrappers by windows powershell scripts. You can directly install hadoop on your windows machine.

Use the following link for downloading the windows version :

```
http://s3.amazonaws.com/public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP-Win/1.1/Beta/HDP-WIN-1.1.0_BETA-hadoop.zip
```